# How to verify if the default values in some drop downs are the current date using Protractor with Jasmine

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

I'm new to protractor and I'm verifying that the default values in some drop downs are the current date: month, day and year

This is my code which I wrote:

```
this.startDateMonthDropdown = element(by.xpath("//op-dropdown[@change.bind='changeStartMonth']"));
    this.startDayInput = element(by.xpath("//input[@value.two-way='startDay']"));
    this.startYearDropdown = element(by.xpath("//op-dropdown[@change.bind='changeStartYear']"));

function checkStartDateIsCurrentDate() {
        let date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        let currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let currentDay = date.getDate() - 1;
        let currentYear = date.getFullYear();
        this.startDateMonthDropdown.getText().then(function (month) {
            expect(month).toEqual(currentMonth)
        });
        this.startDayInput.getAttribute('value').then(function (day) {
            expect(day).toEqual(currentDay)
        });
        this.startYearDropdown.getText().then(function (year) {
            expect(year).toEqual(currentYear)
        });

    }
```

When I run the test, it fails:

- Expected 'July' to equal 7.
- Expected '4' to equal 4.
- Expected '2019' to equal 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getText()` method returns a promise that will be resolved with the element's visible text (string). So you have to convert `currentDay` and `currentYear` to the string.

```
function checkStartDateIsCurrentDate() {
        const date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        const currentMonth = date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' });
        const currentDay = date.getDate() - 1;
        const currentYear = date.getFullYear();

        this.startDateMonthDropdown.getText().then(function (month) {
            expect(month).toBe(currentMonth)
        });
        this.startDayInput.getAttribute('value').then(function (day) {
            expect(day).toBe(`${currentDay}`)
        });
        this.startYearDropdown.getText().then(function (year) {
            expect(year).toBe(`${currentYear}`)
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> - Expected '4' to equal 4.
> - Expected '2019' to equal 2019.

When you interact with an element and write getText(). It takes values as text but if you want to compare with number then you must convert text to number and then verify that.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answers. I managed to fix it and also solved the issue with the month.
This is my final code

function checkStartDateIsCurrentDate() {

```
    let date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    let currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    let currentDay = date.getDate() - 1;
    let currentYear = date.getFullYear();

    this.startDateMonthDropdown.getText().then(function (month) {
        expect(month).toEqual(months[currentMonth])
    });
    this.startDayInput.getAttribute('value').then(function (day) {
        day = parseInt(day);
        expect(day).toEqual(currentDay)
    });
    this.startYearDropdown.getText().then(function (year) {
        year = parseInt(year);
        expect(year).toEqual(currentYear)
    });
}
```